# ¿Cómo sincronizar dos bases de datos en java?

Tags: java, mysql

Trabajo con bases de datos distribuidas cuento con dos bases de datos dbA y dbB que se encuentran en dos computadoras diferentes y un cliente servidor (el que realiza las peticiones en las bases de datos).

Lo que necesito hacer es que al momento de desconectar una base de datos dbB y seguir llenado registros en una base de datos dbA y al momento de conectar la base de datos dbB se actualice automáticamente para que las dos bases de datos contengas los mismo registros.

Nota: necesito implementarlo con java server face.

Comment: Luis, bievenido! Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, revisa [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Java Server Faces se usa para la capa de presentación (el frontend). No tiene utilidad para hacer lo que indicas.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es replicar tu base de datos, esto es independiente de tu lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 1):

Todos las bases de datos relacionales sea oracle, mysql, postgress, sql server, etc. tienen una configuración que se llama replicación, esta configuración permite tener ambas bases de datos en modo espejo, y funciona como has comentado.

Como no has dicho que base usas, te coloco esta [documentación de replicación para mysql](https://manuales.guebs.com/mysql-5.0/replication.html) que es la etiqueta que pusiste.

Te comento que para esto no necesitas ningún lenguaje de programación.